# I'm not getting data from the Angular query, not getting the data from the dropdown. Maybe problem with dto's?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, filter

I have the problem of not getting full data from my form query. In the query I have search and mat select dropdown. I need those selected values back so I can filter elements based on those values. But, I got only my 'title' back but not the EventTypeId also.

This is the data when I put the breakpoint [image]

Controller.......

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<EventDTO>>> Filter([FromQuery] FilterEventsDTO filterEventsDTO)
        {
            var eventsQueryable = context.Event.AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterEventsDTO.Title))  ///ako string nije prazan, znaci ako je unesen
            {
                eventsQueryable = eventsQueryable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(filterEventsDTO.Title));
            }
```

DTO....

```
{
    public class FilterEventsDTO
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int EventTypeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

service in angular

```
  public filter(values: any): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: values });
    console.log('vrijednosti' + params);
    return this.http.get<eventDTO[]>(`${this.apiURL}/filter`, {
      params,
      observe: 'response',
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked on the Angular side that you are actually sending the value by, say, looking at the network tab in your browser's dev tools and checking the payload? Do you see the value there?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually sending the request to the controller.

e.g.

Service:

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl);
}
```

Component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getConfig().subscribe(response =>{
      //do something
    });
  }
```